# Qt 5.0.1 + Visual Studio 2012 + OpenGL

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, qt5

I am trying to convert my Qt4 project to Qt5. It uses OpenGL and works fine on 2008/Qt4.8.4. Please note, that I am retyping in the errors listed and not copying pasting.

- I have recompiled Qt 5.0.1 (sucessfully) using the "-opengl desktop" flag
- Installed the Visual Studio 2012 Add-in

When I compile my code I get the following error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\GL/gl.h(60): error C2371:
  'GLdouble' : redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-
             5.0.1\qtbase\include\qtgui\../../src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h(71) 
   : see declaration of 'GLdouble'
```

if I replace the `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <qopengl.h>` I get

> GL_PROJECTION macro not found

errors, among others. I "should" not be using the OpenGL ES due to the -opengl desktop flag.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5.0.1 did not support (even recompiling) desktop OpenGL. Had rebuild using Qt 5.0.2 or later.